# Slideshow based on jQuery cycle plugin not adjusting to the screen width correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, cycle, easing

I added the jQuery cycle slideshow to my site. 
My slideshow works as it should but the width is a huge issue. 
The width doesn't adapt to the screen, it just takes the width of the image (maximum) and shows it. My big monitor shows everything without problem because the images are incidently as wide as that one, but my smaller monitor shows a horizontal scroll bar and the image doesn't resize.

Is there a specific fix for this or should I try and fix it manually? 
Like, add the detect option on scroll and on page load for $(document).width() to be added to the slideshow. or perhaps a better way? Please help me, I tried everything I thought of so far. New ideas would be welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try a responsive slideshow instead of Cycle.
This might help: http://webdesignandsuch.com/top-30-responsive-jquery-slider-plugins-for-websites/